# PHP FILES reading and writing

Tags: php

Is it possible for me to read from / and write to the same file? If so, could you explain me
how to do that

Answer (score 6):

[Yes it is.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

```
$file = "./test.txt"; 
// open file at the beginning.
$fh = fopen($file, 'r+'); 
//read the first line of the file. (advances pointer to the second line).
$contents = fread($fh); 
// modify contents.
$new_contents = str_replace("hello world", "hello", $contents); 
// make sure you're back at the 0 index.
fseek( $file, 0 );
// write
fwrite($fh, $new_contents); 
// close.
fclose($fh); 
// done!
```

Comment: Was too lazy to write comprehensive sample. +1 to you then ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5 [`file_put_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) is the easiest way:

```
<?php
$file     = 'people.txt';
$current  = file_get_contents($file); // Open the file to get existing content
$current .= "John Smith\n";           // Append a new person to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);   // Write the contents back to the file
?>
```

Comment: I still find it funny that file_get_contents was around for far longer than file_put_contents.

Answer (score -1):

```
file_put_contents("write.txt",file_get_contents("read.txt"));
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is some documentation. You can see there all the parameters you can use in these functions.

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php